# Determine the extrema of this function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let

$b_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-b_i)^2$

So i have calculated the first derivative
$f’(x) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-b_i)$
and the second $f”(x)=2$, so the extrema would be a minimum?

I have tried to calculate the extrema,
$2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-b_i)= 2(nx-\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i)$

$nx= \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i$, so the local minimum would be at $x=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i}{n}$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Correct.  Only one correction that $f^{\prime\prime} = 2n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine, since the function is as regular as we wish. Just one correction, as mentioned by Yathiraj in the comments, the second derivative is $ 2n$ which is still positive so nothing changes in your reasoning.

Comment: Perfect thank you